# How does component know that when page's submit button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using reactjs on electron and I'm having a difficulty on notifying the component when the page's button is clicked. The data on the component will be passed to the page. Maybe the electron is causing the problem to my program, or there is a problem with my code?

Here is my page:

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Form, Button, Popconfirm, Icon, Input, Radio, Collapse, Checkbox } from 'antd';
import Axios from 'axios';
import CompanyContext from '../util/UserContext';
import renderEmpty from 'antd/lib/config-provider/renderEmpty';
import InputOnly from '../components/InputOnly';

export default function Hitung() {

    let [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    let [form, setForm] = useState([]);
    let [soal, setSoal] = useState([]);
    let [pilihan, setPilihan] = useState([]);
    let [test, setTest] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
    let [answer, setAnswer] = useState("");

    let [coba, setCoba] = useState([]);
    let [coba2, setCoba2] = useState([]);

    const company = useContext(CompanyContext);
    let answertemp = []

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getData() {
            try {
                let data = await Axios.get('http://localhost:5000/lelang/getquestion');
                setSoal(data.data.pertanyaan);
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
        getData();
    }, []);

    function onAnswer(data) {
        answertemp.push(data);
        console.log(answertemp);
    }

    function RenderQuestion() {
        if (soal.length != 0) {
            return soal.map(data => {
                switch (data.type_question) {
                    case "input_only":
                        return (<InputOnly data={data} onAnswer={answer => {
                            if(coba.length!=0){
                                for(let i =0;i<coba.length;i++){
                                    if (coba[i].id_question===answer.id_question){
                                        coba[i].answer=answer.answer;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    else if (i<coba.length-1){
                                        continue;
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        setCoba([...coba,answer])
                                    }                       
                                }
                            }
                            else{
                                console.log('add');
                                setCoba([...coba,answer])
                            }

                        }} />)
            })
        }
        else {
            return (<h2 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Loading....</h2>)
        }
    }

    //insert_answer

    async function submit(e) {
        setAnswer(answertemp)
        setLoading(true);
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const token = await Axios.post('http://localhost:5000/lelang/insert_answer', company.data);

        }
        catch (e) {
            alert("error " + e)
        }
        setLoading(false);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Input Penilaian {company.data}</h1>
            <div style={{ padding: '30px' }}>
                <Form>
                    {RenderQuestion()}
                    <button onClick={() => console.log(coba)}>Simpan</button>
                </Form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

and here is my component

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {  Input, Form } from 'antd';


export default function InputOnly (props){
    let[inputOnly,setInputOnly]=useState({});
    let [temp,setTemp]=useState('');
    let [answer,setAnswer]=useState({});
    useEffect(()=>{
        setInputOnly(props.data);
    },[]);
    return (
        <div>
        <p style={{fontWeight:"bold"}}>{inputOnly.question}</p>
        <Form.Item required>
            <Input style={{ width: '20%' }}
            id = {inputOnly.id_question}
            value={temp}
            onChange={data => {
                 setTemp(data.target.value);
                 let answer = {
                     id_question:data.target.id,
                     answer:data.target.value
                 }
                 props.onAnswer(answer);
                // setAnswer(answer);
                 }}
            >
              </Input> 
            <br/>
            </Form.Item>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an `onSubmit` event on your `Form`,

for example here's your form:

```
<Form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
```

Then your `handleFormSubmit` function:

```
const handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('form submitted!');
    // do someting with your form here...
}
```

In your specific case, since you are using [Ant Design form](https://ant.design/components/form/), it would look like this:

(notice how in your code your are missing the main `Form` component along with the `onSubmit` event.  And you are missing a submit `Button`.)

Here's what your Form should look like:

```
<Form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}> 
    <Form.Item required>
        <Input style={{ width: '20%' }}
          id = {inputOnly.id_question}
          value={temp}
          onChange={data => {
             setTemp(data.target.value);
             let answer = {
                 id_question:data.target.id,
                 answer:data.target.value
             }
             props.onAnswer(answer);
            // setAnswer(answer);
             }}
        >
        </Input> 
        <br/>
    </Form.Item>
    <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
    </Form.Item>
</Form>
```

Comment: @Yanka, did this answer your question?  If so, would you mind selecting it as the accepted answer?